# Is there a way to use selenium in your chrome browser Python

Tags: python, selenium

As you might already read from the title I want to ask if it is possible to use the selenium library without the chromedriver? I need it as my default google browser i cant use anything else. And if not is there a similar library which can be use with google chrome?

Comment: This is really to broad of a question for this forum. But why don't you want to use chromedriver? What browser exactly are you trying to use?

Comment: The standard chrome browser. I have been using chromedriver before and it isnt what i look for tbh

Comment: Why not? What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Well i want to make my life a little bit easier and automate some stuff with selenium but i cant switch all the time between my browser i am using as the standard and the chromedriver

Comment: so i need a way to use it without the chromedriver and with my browser im using

Comment: You can use any browser driver, not only Chrome, just download that driver and locate it in your path

Comment: Adding to @vitaliis comment, If you are using Brave, then also chromedriver will work. If you have some thing to work on and don't want to interrupt running automation then you can just set chrome to use headless mode. This comment is just a addon. It is a very broad scenario, kindly list the browser that you are trying to use.

Comment: I think what you are asking is can you have your regular Chrome browser open looking at ESPN, and on the next tab over have some selenium script running.  No, you cannot.